# how to assemble SI7021 I2C command sequence

Tags: embedded

I am using EFR32FG14 starter board.I want to read data from SI7021(Without any driver which does everything for me)
Stricktly by manual, The address of the device is 10000000 which is Hex 80.from the command table shown bellow.
I want to use Measure temperature so i think i should use E3(from mnual shown bellow).But i cant understand the meaning of hold mater mode
What is clock streching?
What is the full command i should send?
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf

[image]

Comment: Clock stretching is defined in I2C specifications. It means that the slave will hold clock low and inhibits the master from communicating until slave is ready and it lets clock run normally. The master must specifically have support for clock stretching.

Answer (score 0):

As @justme noted in his comment, clock stretching is defined that the slave may hold SCL low to pause the master. This is required to give the slave time to do the D/A conversions and have the data ready to send back to the master.

The alternative, as noted in the manual, is for the master to send the command and then to poll the slave until it is ready to send back the data. The slave will NACK the slave-reads from the master until the data is ready.
[image]
Assuming your master supports clock stretching, I suggest you go that route. This avoids having to poll in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a driver that will abstract all the messy I2C details away for you.  The driver is in the board support package.  You can look at the code and see how the driver is implemented to make your own version.  The way clock stretching works is that the master sets the clock high and immediately turns around and checks the state of the clock line (it's bidirectional).  During clock stretching, the slave will hold the clock line low when additional time is needed for internal processing.  Once the master sees that the slave has released the clock line, then the master proceeds as normal.

Here is the driver documentation (Si7021):

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8c.html

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8h.html

Source Code:

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8c_source.html

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8h_source.html

The source code appears pretty straight forward.